# .on Click for a dynamically created item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.7

I am appending a `<li>` and when I try to click it using the new .on event, it doesn't work. I don't want to use the .live event since it might be going to be deprecated in the future.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lbbe/

This works for the first item, if you create a new the alert doesn't work.

Anyone know how can I solve this problem without using live?

Comment: source RE: .live deprecation?

Comment: I second Matt. I don't see that feature going out of use any time soon. `.on()` *was* introduced in jQuery 0.7, but it doesn't replace anything. If you want to look, here are the *only* deprecated functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: Details about the deprecation are right there in the [jQuery doco for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - it's deprecated as of version 1.7. Meanwhile `.delegate()` is "superseded" and `.bind()` is no longer "preferred". As of version 1.7 they recommend using `.on()` instead of all three.

Comment: .live() and .die(): We continue to get many bug reports and see user confusion regarding the quirks of the .live() method. Common issues are now documented on its updated API page. We strongly advise the use of .on() or .delegate() for new code, since they are better APIs. Given its widespread use it’s unlikely we will remove this API in 1.8, but please do update your code as soon as possible.

Comment: P.S. See also http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the info.  I hadn't heard about this yet.

Comment: It's pretty recent, as you can see from the date on that blog post. I found out about it purely by accident earlier this week when I saw another SO question with sample code that used `.on()` - I'd never heard of `.on()` so I looked it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close, all you need to do is change your selector setup:

From

```
$("#bxs li").on('click',function() {
```

To

```
$("#bxs").on('click', 'li',function() {
```

Here's an update to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/2Lbbe/2/

Using the `.on()` function like this is the same as the old `.delegate()` function:

```
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially trying to do what used to be called .delegate(). Attach the event handler to something permanent, then look inside for your targets.

```
$("#bxs").on('click', 'li',function() {
```

[your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lbbe/1/)

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> .on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler )
>
> **Description:** *Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.*

.on() is now capable of serving the purpose of .bind() .live() and .delegate() depending on how it is used. If you want a handler to apply to future items you have to make the final selection using the optional `[,selector]`